# Position FloatingActionButton on the left side

Tags: dart, material-design, flutter

How do I position a `FloatingActionButton` on the left side inside a `Scaffold`?
Currently the only available options are *`centerFloat`, `centerDocked`, `endFloat` and `endDocked`*.

Maybe **Material Design** does not intend to position the FAB at *`startFloat` or `startDocked`*.
That would be fine if **RTL** changed *`endFloat` and `endDocked`* to appear on the left side, but that is not the case.

Comment: you'd have to write your own fab then.  Material Design is pretty picky.  for a consistent UI they simply don't want fabs on the right side.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[In April 2020](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/pull/51465#pullrequestreview-400339300), the available options have been expanded and `startFloat` as well as `startDocked` are included options now.

Here is the full list of available options (see the [`FloatingActionButtonLocation` documentation](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/FloatingActionButtonLocation-class.html)):

- `centerDocked`
- `centerFloat`
- `centerTop`
- `endDocked`
- `endFloat`
- `endTop`
- `miniCenterDocked`
- `miniCenterFloat`
- `miniCenterTop`
- `miniEndDocked`
- `miniEndFloat`
- `miniEndTop`
- `miniStartDocked`
- `miniStartFloat`
- `miniStartTop`
- `startDocked`
- `startFloat`
- `startTop`

---

You can even easily define your own locations using [`StandardFabLocation`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/StandardFabLocation-class.html).

Answer (score 1):

As of 2020, you can use the following:

```
floatingActionButtonLocation: FloatingActionButtonLocation.startFloat
```

A parameter that can be passed to the Scaffold Widget from *material.dart*

Source: PR [51465](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/pull/51465)

Answer (score 0):

There is also another solution to this problem. Fab button by default is always at the bottom end of the screen. So if we wrap our `Scaffold`with a `Directionality` and set its text direction to `TextDirection.rtl`, then the button goes left. but since now the body itself is mirrored, we can wrap the body with another `Directionality` and set its  text direction to `TextDirection.ltr`

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return 
      Directionality(
      textDirection: TextDirection.rtl,
      child:Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Something),
      ),
      body: Directionality(
        textDirection: TextDirection.ltr,
        child: Center(child: const Text('Press the button below!'))),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () {
          
        },
        child: Icon(Icons.navigation),
        backgroundColor: Colors.green,
      ),
    )
      );
  }
```